# jQuery - 2 pseudo selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining jQuery :not and :nth-child selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510128/combining-jquery-not-and-nth-child-selectors)

is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
$("ul#filterlist li:nth-child(3n)").css("marginTop", "0");
```

If I wanted to apply that to the list, but only to those items VISIBLE in the list (some get hidden, I don't want them counted), how would it be achieved? I was thinking something like:

```
$("ul#filterlist li:nth-child(3n)").not(":hidden").css("marginTop", "0");
```

But it won't work. Neither will anything I try with :visible

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of :not, as :not wasn't apart of the solution, it was just the way I thought it would logically work, in which it didn't, thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `filter()`. It will filter down a list of jQuery objects based on the given selector. Since there was no "not `:hidden`" selector I could found, I used the opposite `:visible`.

```
$("ul#filterlist li:nth-child(3n)").filter(":visible").css("marginTop", "0");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to count the hidden elements you can try using the following code.

```
$("ul#filterlist li:visible").filter(function(index){ 
    return (index+1)%3 == 0?true:false;
}).css("marginTop", "0");
```

see the example in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R8HQY/)

Answer (score 1):

try chaining the :selectors

```
$("ul#filterlist li:nth-child(3n):not(:hidden)").css("marginTop", "0");
```

like shown in this answer:

[jQuery - multiple :not selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144976/jquery-multiple-not-selector)

Comment: If it's `:not:hidden`, it must be `:visible`.

Comment: visibility can also be :collapse, although that acts as hidden when used on non-table elements

Comment: another sample $("#divdetails span:nth-child(2):contains('s')")